# Are fat people kidnapped less frequently?

Tags: united-states, criminology, discrimination

This has been [on T-shirts](https://www.amazon.co.uk/FAT-PEOPLE-ARE-HARDER-KIDNAP/dp/B008RMWYCU), [in a *Minions* meme](https://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/63907175.jpg), and even [some Q&A sites](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081031201747AALmFsd):

> Fat people are hard to kidnap.

While the B-flick method of kidnapping (knock 'em unconscious and then carry the mark) is obviously harder the more the victim weighs, it is still something seemingly in the joke territory.

Is there evidence indicating that fat people are less frequent victims of kidnapping compared to fit/lean people?

Comment: Every time I've read that it's clearly been a joke. Can you point to a serious claim about this?

Comment: @DJClayworth the people on the yahoo answer post above seem to be taking this seriously

Comment: Not very seriously if the best answer is "No one really cares about fat people anyway. Only the young, beautiful, and rich are worth abducting."

Comment: I don't think this should be closed because it's based on joking claims, I think answers to jokingly-made claims could potentially be very interesting. However, I think to answer this question we need more info. What exactly is the definition of kidnapping? Are we just talking about child abduction or all abduction? For child abduction, most abductions are by family members, it seems unlikely weight would play a role. If we only consider non-family member abductions, I'm not sure there is enough data to draw a conclusion.

Comment: I like the question. But I don't think it's answerable. I don't think the data that could answer it exist.

Comment: I don't think whether we think data exists should affect how we treat a question. Evidence can surprise us. And James, I don't think we necessarily need to sort all those questions out first.. a good answer might reference how experts tend to define and count those things.